# How do you use just "using" for npgsql instead of trycatchfinally?

Tags: c#, npgsql

In one of my previous questions someone suggested that instead of using trycatch and closing the connection at finally I should just use "using". Can someone give me an example?

I have this code, how do I use just "using" with it?

```
            try
            {
                conn3.Open();
                string sql_check = "SELECT (time_in) FROM timeinout WHERE employee_id = @employee_id AND date = @date";
                using var cmd_check = new NpgsqlCommand(sql_check, conn3);

                cmd_check.Parameters.AddWithValue("employee_id", id);
                cmd_check.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", date);
                cmd_check.Prepare();

                var reader = cmd_check.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn3.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`using` is not a replacement for `try...catch...finally`. It enables you to do away with the `finally` block but, if an exception can be thrown, you still need to catch it. The `using` block guarantees that the object created will be disposed, whether an exception is thrown or not. This:

```cs
var obj = new SomeType();

try
{
    // Use obj here.
}
catch
{
    // Handle exception here.
}
finally
{
    obj.Dispose();
}
```

can AND SHOULD be replaced with this:

```cs
using (obj = new SomeType())
{
    try
    {
        // Use obj here.
    }
    catch
    {
        // Handle exception here.
    }
}
```

Basically, if already have exception handling then you still need exception handling but you don't need to close/dispose locally-created objects in a `finally` block. If you're doing anything else in your `finally` block then you still need it too.

In your case, you should be creating your connection, command and data reader with `using` statements:

```cs
using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand(query, connection))
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            return reader.HasRows;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The data reader will be closed at the end of the inner `using` block and the connection will be closed at the end of the outer `using` block.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I just started c# last week so I'm not really familiar with anything and just seeing someone use this without really explaining anything didn't really help all that much. Thanks again for explaining why and how I should code like this.